# why one leg soleus muscle can be bigger than the other leg?

Tags: running, muscle

I have my left soleus muscle more stronger than my other soleus,  you can see it with no effort, I think it must be because of my form of running,  my right leg is shorter so maybe that could be the problem,  I'm asking just to know if is normal to have a soleus muscle more stronger than other.. 
Im trainning just running btw..

Answer (score 2):

The human body is not perfectly symmetrical.  One side tends to be more dominant than the other.  Having said that, and, barring any consideration for preexisting injuries, there's no reason why you can't train the right calf to bring it up to the level of your left.